# Open document.windows, print it and close it (doesn't close)

Tags: javascript, window

This are the functions I got to -thanks to the search option in stackoverflow and some modifications of mine-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function imprimirElemento(elem)
    {
        abrirElemento($(elem).html());
    }

    function abrirElemento(data) 
    {
        var style = '<style type="text/css">.titulosLightBox {border-bottom: 1px dotted #D1D1D1;color: #333333;font-size: 20px;font-weight: normal;line-height: 18px;margin-bottom: 15px;padding-bottom: 10px;}'+'strong{width:100%;font-weight:bold;}'+'</style>'; 

        var termsAndConditions = window.open('', 'tos', 'height=400,width=600');

        termsAndConditions.document.write('<html><head><title>Politica de Privacidad</title>');
        termsAndConditions.document.write(style);
        termsAndConditions.document.write('</head><body >');
        termsAndConditions.document.write(data);
        termsAndConditions.document.write('</body></html>');
        termsAndConditions.document.close();
        termsAndConditions.print();
        termsAndConditions.document.close(); /*This seems not to work*/
        return true;
    }

</script>
```

It works great, the window it's opened; the file is getting printed with styles and everything but the window its not closed,

any idea why?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line is wrong, because you have already closed the document object. Try `termsAndConditions.close()`

Comment: ? @Walilalu It was not my fault when I got the same idea, but the proxy server at my work prevented a fast answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
termsAndConditions.close();
```